# ¿Comó asignar valor a una propiedad de un tipo personalidado mediante dropdownlist MVC ASP.NET Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, mvc

Saludos,

Tengo el siguiente escenario, en mi modelo `Model` tengo una propiedad de tipo `CustomProperty` la cual quiero asignar mediante interfaz en base a un catalogo de opciones el cual es un `List<CustomProperty>`.Actualmente tengo este código pero al momento de enviar mi formulario al controllador mi propiedad `CustomProperty` aparece como `null`

Modelo:

```
public class Model()
{
  private string Name {get; set; }
  private CustomProperty Status {get; set;}
}
```

CustomProperty:

```
public class CustomProperty()
{
  private int Id {get; set};
  private string DisplayName {get; set;}
}
```

Controlador:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        ViewBag.CustomPropertyCatalog = _status.GetCatalog(); //Regresa el catalogo en forma de List<CustomProperty>
        return View();
}

public ActionResult Index(Model model)
{
    //Aqui la propiedad 'CustomProperty' aparece como nula
    _modelProcessor.Create(model);
}
```

Vista:

```
    <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomProperty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomProperty, new SelectList(
                            (List<Models.CustomProperty>)ViewBag.CustomPropertyCatalog,
                            "Id",
                            "DisplayName"
                        ), new { @class = "form-control" , @name = "CustomProperty" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomProperty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
               </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que asignas el ViewBag no el model

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.CustomPropertyCatalog = _status.GetCatalog(); 

    Model model = new Model()
    {
        Name = "",
        Status = new CustomProperty()
        {
            Id = 1,
            DisplayName = "xx"
        }
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

veras que se crea una instancia de `Model` y se loa pasas al `return View()`

Ademas en la clase defienes la propiedad como `Status` (no como CustomProperty) por lo que debes usar

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new SelectList(
        (List<Models.CustomProperty>)ViewBag.CustomPropertyCatalog,
        "Id",
        "DisplayName"
    ), new { @class = "form-control" , @name = "CustomProperty" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

al definir el combo `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status ...`